# 20.04 + Chromium + changed hostname

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, chromium

I am having an issue with getting a locked profile on Chromium after changing the hostname.

What is really confusing is I cannot find a Singleton* file. Yes, I have looked in the config folder, it's not there.

I am pretty stumped at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently snap is the problem here.  The Singleton* files are located at

```
/home/${USER}/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Singleton*
```